# Данные из input превратить в заголовок ссылку (вн)

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

Получаю страницу getcontentom, ищу слова на ней по инпуту в веб форме, 
нужна реализация как сделать такой поиск чтобы искомый запрос из инпута выводился заголовком и ссылкой одновременно и нажимая на него можно было провалиться в страницу где это слово нашлось

```
// Если пришел запрос =)
if ($_POST['search']) {
  // Преобразование в массив
  $key = array($_POST['text']);
  $d = file_get_contents('http://');
  // Ищем по направлению
  foreach($key as $k) {
    if(strpos($d, $k) !== false) {
      $i++;
     // Если есть ключ в тексте выводим весь документ
     echo "$i ключик есть "."<br />";
     echo '<a href=". $d .">' . $_POST['text'] . '</a>'; // здесь не получилось
    } else {
      $i=$i+1;
      echo "$i по направлению ничего не найдено"."<br />";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки, что у вас не получилось ?

Comment: А что мешало отредактировать вопрос и вставить код туда?

Comment: `$d = file_get_contents('http://');` - это реальный код или заглушка?

Comment: `$key = array($_POST['text']);` - этим кодом вы надеетесь разбить фразу на слова?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, вы в `file_get_contents` подставляете полный url страницы?
В переменной `$d` у вас что? Полный текст страницы или ссылка на страницу? Потому как в html вы пытаетесь вставить именно как ссылку

Comment: Не стоит вандализировать вопросы. Откатил к предыдущей редакции.

Comment: Вам же уже выше сказали, не надо заниматся вандализмом.

Comment: @user309013, не надо портить вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тег `a` в атрибут `href` нужно передавать ссылку на страницу, а не контент с этой страницы:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$d = file_get_contents($url);
...
echo '<a href="'. $url .'">' . $_POST['text'] . '</a>'
```

Comment: Можно просто вывести url - `echo "$url";`. Контент страницы вывести не получится, потому как там и тело страницы и заголовок. Но можно отобразить в iframe: `echo '<iframe src=" . $url . "></iframe>'.
P.S. Если ответ помог, то можно его принять как ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Не выражает все равно